# IIS 7, HttpHandler and HTTP Error 500.21

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, httphandler, ihttphandler

On IIS 7, I'm trying to use custom HttpHandler for my ASP.NET web application. I use pipeline mode "classic", .NET version is 4.0.30319, my web.config configuration for the handler is:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
    <add name="MyHandler" path="*.myExtension" verb="*" type="Company.App.UI.Controls.MyHandler, Company.App.UI" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

When I invoke this handler, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "MyHandler" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list
```

I did a google search, the most of people fix this issue by re-registering ASP.NET by aspnet_regiis.exe /i command, but this is **not** working for me (the command finishes, I restart the IIS, but same error). I tried it on two different servers, but got the same result.

What else should I try? Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's not possible to configure an IIS managed handler to run in classic mode. You should be running IIS in integrated mode if you want to do that.

You can learn more about modules, handlers and IIS modes in the following blog post:

[IIS 7.0, ASP.NET, pipelines, modules, handlers, and preconditions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx)

> For handlers, if you set preCondition="integratedMode" in the
>    mapping, the handler will only run in integrated mode.  On
>   the other hand, if you set preCondition="classicMode" the handler will
>   only run in classic mode.  **And if you omit both of these, the handler
>   can run in both modes, although this is not possible for a managed
>   handler**.

Comment: I got the same problem. My server is using Window server 2008 R2, IIS 7.0. I come to this folder c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ and run this command aspnet_regiis -i then the problem was solved.

Comment: Me too did the aspnet_regiis and it worked :) Thanks @nvtthang

Comment: I come to this folder c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ and run this command aspnet_regiis -i then the problem was solved

Comment: thank you so much!! it worked as soon as I set siteManager.AppPool.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;

Answer (score 13):

Luckily, it’s very easy to resolve. Run the follow command from an elevated command prompt:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

If you’re on a 32-bit machine, you may have to use the following:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: This ONLY worked for me if I removed the .exe

I don't know why.

Comment: It worked for me as well on a Win 7 Pro box. Had to run the command prompt as administrator.

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem and was solved by running the following in run

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Comment: Worked for me too, but I have _no idea why_. @Paul Gathuo Wagana, can you explain what this magical command actually **does**?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and just solved it.  I had posted my own question on stackoverflow:

[Can't PUT to my IHttpHandler, GET works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285257/cant-put-to-my-ihttphandler-get-works-fine/33290675#33290675)

The solution was to set runManagedModulesForWebDavRequests to true in the modules element.  My guess is that once you install WebDAV then all PUT requests are associated with it.  If you need the PUT to go to your handler, you need to remove the WebDAV module and set this attribute to true.

```
<modules runManagedModulesForWebDavRequests="true">
...
</modules>
```

So if you're running into the problem when you use the PUT verb and you have installed WebDAV then hopefully this solution will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

On windows server 2016 i have used:

`dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all`

Also can be done via Powershell:

`Install-WindowsFeature .NET-Framework-45-Features`

Answer (score 0):

This situation happens because you haven't installed/start service of ASP.net.

Use below command in windows 7,8,10.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution that I've found is that you should have to change the .Net Framework back to v2.0 by Right Clicking on the site that you have manager under the Application Pools from the Advance Settings.