# 500.21 Bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am getting the error:

HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "CloudConnectHandler" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list

my web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="CloudConnectHandler" verb="*" path="CloudConnect.aspx" type="CloudConnectHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" batch="false">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
        <identity impersonate="true" />
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="CloudConnectAuthorization" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="ConnectionInfo" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="DefaultChannel" value="xxxx" />
    <add key="LoginValidationConnectionString" value="xxxx" />
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="protobuf-net" publicKeyToken="257b51d87d2e4d67" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.640" newVersion="2.0.0.640" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

There is a lot of advice out there indicating that asp.net is not installed correctly.  The usual fix is to run:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

or

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

I have run both, without any errors.  I have restarted IIS, but the problem still persists.  The site is using an application pool.  The app pool is started, .net framework = 4.0, Managed Pipeline = Classic, Identity = LocalSystem.

I've spent the last couple hours trying to figure out what the problem is.  I'm hoping someone can help.

Comment: I had to add the attribute <add requireAccess="Read" ...> to solve the 500.21 error that I was getting

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try switching to Integrated mode.  See the following thread:

[IIS 7, HttpHandler and HTTP Error 500.21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069415/iis-7-httphandler-and-http-error-500-21)

Comment: I had switched it to integrated, which caused a different error.  Once I fixed that, everything started working properly.  Thank you.

Comment: "Down vote" for this. I already had integrated mode enabled. @Armaan answers it brief but perfectly.

Comment: This answer is valid, it resolve my problem, I used NET 3.5 and got the 500.21 Error. switch to integrated mode resolved my problem.

Answer (score 187):

**Please follow these steps:**

1) Run the command prompt as administrator.

2) Type either of the two lines below in the command prompt:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

or

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your answer. This answer has been flagged for review because of its brevity. While your answer may be technically correct, it could be improved with some more text, explaining what the underlying problem is that the OP is having, and why your answer works.

Comment: here's the more text. cause it works muhahahaha +1. I think the real reason is if you install 4.5.1 first then stick IIS on it doesn't automagically recognize right. or I have that in reverse order. either way. this worked for me

Comment: This is the solution!

Comment: I'm building a new 2008 R2 server (yes, in the year 2015) and I installed 4.5.x first and then stuck IIS on afterwards.. like @hubsonBropa mentioned in his comment. This got me past the first of many hurdles.

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.5.x or 4.6.x, don't be fooled by the answer mentioning 4.0 and thinking it doesn't apply to you. This problem can be related to the order of installation of .NET before IIS, as it was for me. Running the command (in my case the 64 bit version) fixed it even though my application is using .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: Why do I do the same thing over and over?!?!: bang head on wall for a few hours *then* check stackoverflow, then get back to work....moron.

Comment: I could not execute this command in Windows 10 "This option is not supported on this version of the operating system". 

I had to go to feature installation in control panel "Turn Windows features on or off".

Answer (score 52):

I ran into this error on a fresh build of Windows Server 2012 R2. IIS and .NET 4.5 had been installed, but the ASP.NET Server Role (version 4.5 in my case) had not been added. Make sure that the version of ASP.NET you need has been added/installed like ASP.NET 4.5 is in this screenshot.

[image: ASP.NET Server Role]

Comment: It is now ASP.NET 4.7 (Svr 2016)

Answer (score 34):

To fix the problem, I tried to run

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

However It didn't work for me. I have to run another command line in CMD window as administrator. Here is the command:

> dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45

or

> dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all

Hope it will help.

Comment: This solved it for me as well on Window 10 Preview Build 10074 with IIS 10.

Comment: The dism command worked for me after removing the `%` from the beginning. So I ran: `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45 /all`.

Comment: Works on Windows Server 2016! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I got this error on my ASP.Net 4.5 app on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Go to start menu -> "Turn windows features on or off".  A wizard popped up for me.

Click Next to Server Roles

I had to check these to get this to work, located under Web Server IIS->Web Server-> Application Development (these are based on Jeremy Cook's answer above):

[image]

Then click next to Features and make sure the following is checked:

[image]

Then click next and Install.  At this point, the error went away for me.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

This is because IIS 7 uses http handlers from both `<system.web><httpHandlers>` and `<system.webServer><handlers>`. if you need CloudConnectHandler in your application, you should add `<httpHandlers>` section with this handler to the `<system.web>`:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="CloudConnect.aspx" type="CloudConnectHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

and also add `preCondition` attribute to the handler in `<system.webServer>`:

```
<handlers>
  <add name="CloudConnectHandler" verb="*" path="CloudConnect.aspx" type="CloudConnectHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue in Windows 10 when I needed IIS instead of IIS Express. New Web Project failed with OP's error. Fix was

`Control Panel > Turn Windows Features on or off > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features`

tick `ASP.NET 4.7` (in my case)

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was getting this error message when using `PUT` or `DELETE` to WebAPI.  I also tried re-registering .NET Framework as suggested but to no avail.

I was able to fix this by disabling WebDAV for my individual application pool, this stopped the 'bad module' error when using `PUT` or `DELETE`.

### Disable WebDAV for Individual App Pool:

1. Click the affected application pool
2. Find `WebDAV Authoring Tools` in the list
3. Click to open it
4. Click `Disable WebDAV` in the top right.

[This link](http://www.exactsoftware.com/Docs/DocView.aspx?DocumentID=%7Bc288fa96-2eea-414f-843f-29a2a1531405%7D) is where I found the instructions but it's not very clear.

Comment: My problem exactly. Put and Delete didn't work with WebDav enabled. Thanks for sharing your finding!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem every time I deployed a new website or updated an existing one using **MSDeploy**.

**I was able to fix this by unloading the app domain using MSDeploy** with the following syntax:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="Default Web Site/myAppName",recycleMode=UnloadAppDomain
```

You can also stop, start, or recycle the application pool - more details here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee522997%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

While Armaan's solution helped get me unstuck, it did not make the problem go away permanently.

Answer (score 0):

if it is IIS 8 go to control panel, turn windows features on/off and enable Bad "Named pipe activation" then restart IIS. Hope the same works with IIS 7

Answer (score -1):

I discovered that the order of adding roles and features is important.
On a fresh system I activate the role "application server" and there check explicitly .net, web server support and finally process activation service
Then automatically a dialogue comes up that the role "Web server" needs to be added also.

Answer (score -1):

Install .NET framework as below, it will work .NET version ***4.5*** as well.

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

Some time only give `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` don't work so give `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir` in above path.