# Custom handlers for ASP.NET 2.0 Website in Classic mode in IIS 8.5 throwing 500 error

Tags: asp.net, iis, httphandler, iis-8.5

I have ASP.NET 2.0 website running in Classic Mode.
Server 2001/IIS 8.5.
I get this error when calling custom handler (something.abc).

[image]

I have my handler(something.abc) added to `<system.webServer><handlers>` section

```
<add name="Something.abc" verb="GET,HEAD" path="something.abc" type="ABC.MyHttpHandler, ABC" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
```

It was working fine in local IIS Express.

On Server when I changed the Application Pool setting: **Enable 32-bit Applications= True** it started working.

**Question:** Why I had to turn 32-bit mode and is there any way I can make it work without enabling 32-bit?

Comment: Your handler is probably targeting x86

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I have the handler as above in my edited question.

Comment: Oh, I see, so it's just the isapi dll.  Well, you're using the one in Framework directory, not Framework64 directory, so it's 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with an application running on a new Windows Server 2016 box with IIS 10.

It was working on the old Server 2012 box because that one had the 32-bit Oracle client installed, but the new server had the 64-bit Oracle client installed, and I was therefore unable to set **Enable 32-bit Applications= True** without causing other problems.

The worker process was also set up to use **Classic pipeline** instead of Integrated, another setting that I could not change in order to get this to work. ASP.NET was properly installed too. (i.e. [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912617/500-21-bad-module-managedpipelinehandler-in-its-module-list) did not help me.)

I had:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Something.abc" verb="*" path="something.abc" type="ABC.MyHttpHandler, ABC" resourceType="Unspecified" />
```

To solve this issue I added *BOTH* of these attributes (it did not work with only one or the other):

```
 modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
```

i.e. final result was:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Something.abc" verb="*" path="something.abc" type="ABC.MyHttpHandler, ABC" resourceType="Unspecified" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" />
```