# Internal Server Error (500.21)

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service

I occasionally get a 500.21 error in my application that contains the following text:

"Handler "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list"

I have searched the web and have typically found things the seem to mention adding and removing installed components.  However, this application is hosted in an Azure Web App so these suggestions seem to be irrelivent.

Can anyone recommend things to try?  I see an entry for the ExtensionlessUrlHander in the configuration file but I am not sure if this is necessary or how the configuration might need to be updated.

Comment: Have you referenced this [blog](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/12/07/configuring-iis-verbs-for-aspnet-web-api-on-windows-azure-websites-and-elsewhere.html)? `if you need those methods or want to provide your own HTTP methods, here’s the bit of configuration to add to your Web.config file`

Comment: I am not sure if the referenced article is of much use.  The current configuration is already set to remove and then add the "ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" handler.  This is configured by default when creating a new Web API project.  The configuration to add the handler specifies all verbs so some of the unique ones (such as HEAD or PATCH) should be included.

Comment: See this post here for help with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069415/iis-7-httphandler-and-http-error-500-21

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance running your App in `classic` mode of IIS and is your App an ASP.NET Application ? Check a previous SO on this [IIS 7, HttpHandler and HTTP Error 500.21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069415/iis-7-httphandler-and-http-error-500-21)

You can check this by going to Application Settings for the Web App and looking out for **Managed Pipeline Version** setting.

Comment: No...I confirmed this morning that the application is not running in "Classic" mode.